# printf with consecutive function as argument, undefined behavior

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I know below code block generates "undefined behavior"

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * foo(int i) {
    char static str[100];
    str[0] = 0;
    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d", i);
    printf("foo %s\n", str);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    printf("main %s %s\n", foo(12), foo(4));

    return 0;
}
```

I wanna know this code block matches which circumstances of "undefined behavior" in "ISO/IEC 9899:1999(E): Programming Languages - C".

This one ?? "Between two sequence points, an object is modified more than once, or is modified
and the prior value is read other than to determine the value to be stored (6.5)."  However here is function call....

Comment: No. Each function call to `foo` is a sequence point. The order of calls is not *specified*, but it is not undefined. Using 3 times `%s` with 2 strings is undefined.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  I updates code. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no instance of a object being modified more than once between two sequence point in this code.

The two calls to `foo` as arguments to a function is not undefined behavior but **unspecified behavior**.  This means that two or more things can happen, but the standard doesn't specify which one.

In this example, since function parameters can be evaluated in any order the two calls to `foo` can be in any order.  And because the function always returns a pointer to a static buffer, the same number will be printed twice, but there is no guarantee whether you'll get "4 4" or "12 12".

Comment: HI,Thanks very much!!  I just checked  standard. Are you talking about "— The order in which the function designator, arguments, and subexpressions within the
arguments are evaluated in a function call (6.5.2.2)." ???

Comment: @nathan yes, specifically paragraph 10: *There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual
arguments but before the actual call. Every evaluation in the calling function (including
other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the
execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to
the execution of the called function*

Comment: I did not find your quotes in "ISO/IEC 9899:1999(E): Programming Languages - C" .... could you gimme your reference?? Thanks!!

Comment: It comes from the current C standard, i.e. C11: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf